# ExtJS 4 - CSS - PropertyGrid Column Header/Property Style

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Good day. I have a Web App and I want to change the style of the column header/property of my Property Grid. I managed to change the column names programatically as such (this is a function that listens on the before render event of the PropertyGrid):

```
onPropertygridBeforeRender: function(component, eOpts) {
    var cols = component.getView().getHeaderCt().getGridColumns();
    cols[0].setText("Mode");
    cols[1].setText("Amount");
},
```

However, I doubt that I can format the property programatically as well. So far, what I've tried is the `renderer` function of the PropertyGrid as such:

```
    renderer: function(v){
        return '<div style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal;">' + v + '</span></div>';
    },
```

However, that only changes the cell. In my case, it only changed the rows below the `Amount` column and not the `Mode` column. Also, I noticed that if I changed the contents of the property grid, for example I change any of the content in the `Amount` column, the formatting disappears.

I also tried the `bodyStyle` as such:

```
bodyStyle: {
        background: '#ffc',
        padding: '0px'
},
```

However, that doesn't affect the column headers or the rows under the `Mode` column. It is also prone to being "reset" if the user changes the values of the fields.

Does anyone know how to style/format the Property Grid properly? I can't code CSS to save my life so any help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS yo change your grid visual properties

```
// This changes the CSS for all cells
.x-grid-cell {
    color: #FF0000;
}
// This changes the CSS for the Value Column    
.x-grid-cell-value {
    text-align: right;
    font-family:Arial; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 15px; 
    line-height: normal;
}
// This changes the CSS for the Name Column
.x-grid-cell-name {
    font: italic bold 16px Helvetica;
}
```

Obviously this will change the CSS for every grid in your project, so if you want to change for this grid only, add this to the grid: `cls: 'myCustomGrid'` and then add `.myCustomGrid` before the the classes names (eg. `.myCustomGrid .x-grid-cell { color: #FF0000; }`)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up how to use `cls`, I couldn't get how it works before.